# Are continuous maps generically homotopic to a regular map?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be smooth algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $f$ be a continuous map from complex points of $X$ to $Y$. Are there Zariski opens $U$ and $V$ inside $X\times \mathbb{A}^1$ and $Y\times \mathbb{A}^1$ respectively such that $U$ contains $X\times\{0\}$ and $X\times \{1\}$ (similarly $V$ contains $Y\times \{0\}$ and $Y\times \{1\}$) with the property that a continuous map $g$ from $U$ to $V$ can be assigned to $f$ in a way that $g|_{X\times \{0\}}= f$ and $g|_{X\times \{1\}}$ is a regular morphism?

Comment: The restriction of g doesn't have target Y but V, so it can't be f.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Probably it is meant that the restriction of $g$ maps $X\times 0$ into $Y\times 0$ sitting in $V$.

Comment: I think $V$ is not needed: aren't we asking for some $g:U\to Y$ restricting to $f$ on $X\times \{0\}$ and to a morphism on $X\times \{1\}$?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly You are right $V$ is not necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the answer is negative.

For instance, let $X=Y$ be a smooth curve of genus $g\geq 3$ with $\operatorname{Aut}(X)=\{\mathrm{id} \}$, and take as $f \colon X \to X$ an isotopically non-trivial diffeomorphism.

Comment: Does the situation of the problem imply that a diffeomorphism on one edge has to go an automorphism (regular map) on the other edge?

Comment: It seems to me that your situation implies that there is a homotopy (and so an isotopy, since we are in real dimension $2$) between $f$ and a regular map $X \to X$. I am missing something?

Comment: @FracescoPolizzi Ok so now I have 2 questions: 1) In this case you imply that a rational homotopy is actually a homotopy (you can fill in the potential holes in $X\times \mathbb{A}^1$ and assume that $U$ and $V$ are just $X\times \mathbb{A}^1$) 2) If $f$ is a diffeomorphism then any homotopy to a regular map has to be an automorphism (should have a regular inverse). Now giving these two your counter-example works. But I don't know why these two are true.

Comment: Well, regarding (1) it suffices to have inside $X \times \mathbb{A}^1$ a subset homeomorphic to $X \times [0, 1]$ where the rational homotopy is everywhere defined (in order to have a genuine topological homotopy), and this should follow from the fact that Zariski open set are very big with respect to the Euclidean topology.

Comment: Regarding (2): a regular, non-constant map $X \to X$ must be an automorphism, since the degree is $1$ by Hurwitz formula (the fact that the inverse is also regular follows by the projectivity of $X$, I think this is proved somewhere in Griffiths-Harris, but I can look for a reference if you need it).

Comment: See J. Harris, *Algebraic Geometry*, Theorem 14.9 and Corollary 14.10, for a proof of the fact that smooth bijection of smooth projective  varieties is an isomorphism.

Comment: A simple concrete counterexample could be $X=Y=\mathbb{P}^1$, $f=$ complex conjugation. This induces $\times(-1)$ on $H_2(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathbb{Z})$, so it cannot be homotopic to a morphism, right?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly: the same argument can be applied to every anti-biholomorphism (for instance, complex conjugation if $X$ is defined over $\mathbb{R}$) of a variety of odd dimension, right? In fact, in odd dimension anti-biholomorphisms are orientation-reversing.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: Yes, assuming $X$ proper, I guess.